# simpleLoess() warning message with ggplot call

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running the following ggplot call:

```
ggplot(IL2, aes(x=Year, y= Mwhs, col=Source)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=Year, y=Mwhs), se=F)
```

The plot that shows up looks ok, but it gives me the following error messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
  Chernobyl! trL>n 6
2: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
  Chernobyl! trL>n 6
```

What are these warnings referring to?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: this short example from the UCBAdmnissions dataset does it: structure(list(adm = c(0.644158628081458, 0.632478632478632, 
0.350762527233115, 0.339646464646465, 0.251712328767123, 0.0644257703081232
), pref = c(0.115755627009646, 0.0427350427350427, 0.645969498910675, 
0.473484848484849, 0.672945205479452, 0.477591036414566)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("adm", 
"pref")) with ggplot2 version 2.2.0

Comment: I am guessing you don't have enough data points to make loess smoothing.

Comment: a bit on the history of this awesome error message: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-September/038581.html